# Showing term description on terms page that are displayed using views

Tags: 7, views

I am currently using a view to override Drupal's core taxonomy pages. Unlike the core handling of taxonomy pages, views does not display the current term's description. Is there a good way to display a term's description through views or would I need to make a template file for the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood correctly... simply add the field `Taxonomy: Term description` to your view:

[image: Taxonomy Term Description]

Comment: Well that is if I want to make a list of terms right? I want to make a list of nodes in a certain term

Answer (score 3):

1: Create a view much like this one (It is a term view using the term ID as a contextual filter then showing an unformatted list of the description field):

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'catalog_taxonomy_term_descriptio';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Catalog Taxonomy Term Description';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Catalog Taxonomy Term Description';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Term description */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['id'] = 'description';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['field'] = 'description';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['hide_empty'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['hide_alter_empty'] = 1;
/* Contextual filter: Taxonomy term: Term ID */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['id'] = 'tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['field'] = 'tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['default_action'] = 'empty';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['default_argument_skip_url'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['break_phrase'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['tid']['not'] = 0;
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'catalog' => 'catalog',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'catalog-taxonomy-term-description';
```

2: Go into your taxonomy term view (I'm assuming you have already edited/overridden this) and set the Header in the Page Settings section to Global: View area. In the settings for that you will be able to select your view description view. This will cause the term description to show up the top of the page while displaying the related nodes below it.

Answer (score 1):

@carsonblack's solution worked for me. Initially it wasn't working, but I just needed to tick the box that says "Inherit contextual filters" - which is found on the Global: View area settings.